# How should I configure Apollo Nuxt module to provide the AWS Amplify api key with my queries?

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo-client, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to communicate from a Nuxt frontend with the [nuxt apollo module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module), to an AWS Amplify graphQL backend.

The backend requires to provide an API key but I don't know how I can set this up in my nuxt.config file.

When I test requests on the API from AWS AppSync, I see in my network tab that the key is provided in the request header as the value of `x-api-key` key. However, I don't know how to setup nuxt apollo to provide it at each call.

Moreover, if I edit the apollo request to add this header with the correct value, it works as expected.

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from one of my codebases of how to achieve normal connection (for mutations and queries):

```
notifications: {
    httpEndpoint: `https://${process.env.VUE_APP_WS_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT || 'localhost:4030'}/graphql`,
    httpLinkOptions: {
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': process.env.VUE_APP_WS_API_KEY || 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm on a tight schedule, I used aws-amplify client instead of Nuxt Apollo. If someone answers on how to achieve it with Nuxt Apollo, I'll switch the validated answer to her/his.

EDIT: the related ticket [is here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/318)